# Scalability of multi-site rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, scalability

I am beginning work on a new Rails project that is based on the premise of allowing users to create their own "sites." Each "site" would be a subdomain of the root domain (we'll use example.com). So if user Foo wants to create his own site at bar.example.com, each page request to a bar.example.com page would require fetching the a row in a sites table based on the subdomain.

My question is not how to code a multisite app, I think I have a pretty good grasp on that. My question is, from a scalability and performance perspective, would it be better to simply generate a new rails project for each site a user creates? Or is it ok run all sites out of one rails app. If numbers are necessary, let's assume I have 1 million users, each with a maximum of 5 sites, with each site bringing in around 1,000 hits a day.

I realize this is kind of a broad question, and mostly depends on my implementation of either method to reach a feasible solution, but any suggestions in terms of the best way to write this, including optimizing the DB, etc. would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It would be exponentially easier to have 1 rails app with millions of subdomains compared to millions of rails apps.

Check out this railscast for how to start with subdomains: http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't ever consider doing something like this with multiple Rails projects, because of the need to maintain all the code. By keeping it centralized, you can change the functionality of everybody's sites at once.

I think you might also run into memory issues by having all of those copies of Rails instantiated, too.

Answer (score 0):

@Solomon is right. Heroku.com is using same concept for it's users to demonstrate users' applications.